# React binding function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen a lot of reactjs places where a function is called like below

> onChange = {this.fileSelected}

whereas I have seen its usage like below as well

> onClick={() => this.clearDisplay()}

I want to ask if they both mean the same or is there any difference and what to use when.

Answer (score 1):

If you use First:

```
onChange = {this.fileSelected}
```

It will only execute when onChange is called. If you want to bind this function then you have to declare it in the component class constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // your state
    };
    this.clearDisplay = this.clearDisplay.bind(this);
}
```

The Second one:

```
onClick={() => this.clearDisplay()}
```

This defines an anonymous function but, does not call it. Only when onClick is fired is it called. However, in some cases using an anonymous function can cause performance issues. That anonymous function will be defined on every render - and if you have a component that is re-rendering very often it can hurt the performance of your application. If you are sure that the component will not be rendered often, an anonymous function should be fine for convenience.

Comment: `onChange = {this.fileSelected}` will not execute on every render.
It will only execute when onChange is called. that's what callback functions do as per  ES6.

Answer (score 1):

`onChange={this.fileSelected}`

**Is preferable because it is able to not cause unnecessary re-renders.**

`onClick={() => this.clearDisplay()}`

When you pass an anonymous function like this it will actually be called on all instances of the class instead of the one that the event was triggered on.

From a high level in may seem like they have the same behavior but if you were to use the second method consistently through a large codebase the performance of your application would suffer.

This article goes more in depth on the issue:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Comment: The first option is *able* to not cause unnecessary rerenders. It doesn't automatically make everything better.

Answer (score -1):

> onChange = {this.fileSelected}

This will direct bind *fileSelected* function to *onChange* method. so when onChange method called it will call *fileSelected* function.

while

> onClick={() => this.clearDisplay()}

This will call *onClick* function in which you are calling *clearDisplay* function. so when you onClick method called, first anonymous called in which clearDisplay function called. So basically in this method two functions called. in this methos you can do additional calls or other things

e.g.

```
onClick={() => {
  console.log("this function called")
  this.clearDisplay();
}
```